# Access IIS express hosted service over network?

Tags: asmx, iis-express

How can I access web services hosted on IIS express from a remote computer? I do not have admin privileges in the host machine.
Is there any setting/configuration with which I can make this available over the network?

Answer (score 0):

Without administrator permissions you are stuck. You must be able to change firewall settings at least,

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx